# Jomsocial facebook connect make blank my website frontend and backend

Tags: facebook, authentication, joomla

I have a Jomsocial site that was working well with "hellome" module for login; after i enable in the backend "jomsocial facebook connect" and i disconnect from the admin panel, i can't get the possibility to login again, but only see as result a blank page.

the same problem on frontend. i'm desperate because i can't change settings without a backend access!
Please help: how can i disable fb connect via ftp?

Comment: A blank page usually points to something going really wrong, so that the script _dies_ because of a fatal error and can not even send an error message as HTML output any more. You should check the logfiles (server error.log, php error log plus additional logfiles joomla might write to), to see what went awry.

Answer (score 0):

ok i get by modifing table jos_plugin in my database, setting to 0 ( unpublished ) jomsocial plugin to facebook connect. After that i have to get it work with hello me module, but it's another story..